# Log4j2: How to find out in console logs whether the logging configuration file has been located

Tags: logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I want to know if `log4j2` has found my configuration file or the errors it encountered while looking for it. Basically, I want to see `log4j2`'s own logs.

I'm actually trying to put the (non-standard) log file name and location in `web.xml` as described [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#ContextParams) and I want to know why its not getting picked up

Here's my web.xml

```
        <context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:log4j2-assessment.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>isLog4jContextSelectorNamed</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
```

(**Additional info**: Why I need to do all this is because I want to give a custom name to my `log4j2.xml` file and I cannot do that in application.properties using the `logging.file` property because I have a custom name for `application.properties` itself, and with a custom name, the `logging.file` property isn't loaded by Spring in time for the logging to start)

P.S: If I don't rename the `log4j2.xml` file, it gets picked up without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to see log4j2's own logs.

You can set the logging level of the logger to TRACE with help of run configs:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE
```

Source: [here (scroll to "Status Messages")](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/configuration.html)

[image: Before a configuration is found, status logger level can be controlled with system property]

The output displays explicitly what config files are searched and where.
Please, be aware that there is no ouput, if a file was successfully found, it just stops searching as soon as one was found.

To proof this works, just add a dummy log4j2.properties - log4j2 should stop searching any config file after that, meaning the filename searched for last is the one that was found.